# I need to upload a photo with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to upload a photo on a protected web page. I am using selenium.
Everything is fine until the following lines:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a3upGLy67EoZwmBxHrXXMk"]/section[9]/label[1]/div/input').send_keys('C:/Users/on/Desktop/Proy/1.jpg')
time.sleep(15)
```

The problem is: The path of the photo is copied in the field without problem, but the photo is not loaded when I click with selenium on the send button.

This field is a line-picker, when I click, the window to select the image opens. The html code of the widget (line-piker) is:

```
<div class="widget file-picker">
    <input class="ignore fake-file-input" placeholder="Haga clic aquí para subir el archivo. (<10MB)" readonly="">
```

What dou you recommend me?

Comment: Is it possible to share the page URL ?

Comment: Is a protected web page: KoboToolbox. You need an account.